# Where should custom validation be placed in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Use case:
At springboot startup I want to validate some thing regarding annotations and application.properties file. So I want spring startup to fail if the rules 
are violated.

What is the standard place to do this in Spring?
I have read this article: [Baeldung - Article](https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring)

Two solution that I like:

1. CommandLineRunner/ApplicationRunner
2. Registering an ApplicationListener

Are these OK for validating purpose as entry point?

Answer (score 0):

You can create one validator bean and put all different validation logics in different methods and annotate them by `@PostConstruct`

Answer (score 0):

Unless your configuration is changing frequently,
and it seems likely that it should not change frequently,
you only need to perform this type of validation in an integration test.
Just write a jUnit test that loads the configuration then performs the validation.
These are often, wrongly, called unit tests (because they use jUnit) but are actually integration tests.